# Want to select all the text of <p> tag from a <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to select all the text between

tags from a parent tag. 
How to do this. using regex

This is my sample string

```
<p>sddsd</p>
<pre>
<p>line 1</p>
<p>line 2</p>
<p><line 3</p>
</pre>
```

I want to select only this

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I am using this regex, but it is selecting only first line of p tag

```
<pre>\n<p>(.+)<\/p>
```

use this website to run your regex

https://regex101.com/

Please help me...

Comment: Why use regex? This is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @trincot : then what i should use?

Comment: is a string  or html element

Comment: A [DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) will do the job nicely.

Comment: @trincot : i cant use this right now, i have written regex for my full project, and i am stucking in this. please help me through regex.

Comment: Sorry, I wont. It is bad practice. Good luck.

Comment: You should start with valid HTML. A P element is not allowed as a child of a PRE element. Perhaps you should write a simple DOM parser?

Answer (score 0):

You could do with [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) .No need regex

```js
var str = '<p>sddsd</p><pre><p>line 1</p><p>line 2</p><p>line 3</p></pre>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
console.log(htmlDoc.querySelector('pre').textContent)
```

Comment: The OP HTML is invalid, so the results will be implementation dependent. Most likely the P elements will be moved out of the PRE element, so the result **might** be an empty string.

Comment: i think its a typo on third  element  of `<p><line 3</p>`